# sending an embed from google scripts to discord using Webhook

Tags: google-apps-script, discord, webhooks

im now working on sending a notification when triggered that sends an embedded message to discord from google scripts.

I've gone through multiple resources however cannot find one that works.
I can get a simple message sent across using webhooks however anytime attempt to insert an embed it doesnt seem to send, however dont get any errors appearing.

```
  var discordUrl = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/814799155587055667/4NuUkPYbXqgvpiAmxURnisPLGC6eJUO3uMH2jEzP0-cQkzy1Ohy2LyhB6OK5kKQdwOuM';

var options = {
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
 "method": "post",
 "payload": JSON.stringify({
    "username": "Compensation Notifier",
   "avatar_url": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/46/f2/cb/46f2cb9bd2c4be10400634ff47ba23ae.png",
  "embeds": [{
      "author":{
        "name": "Record Added!",
      },
  "title": staff + " Recorded " + user + "Compensation",
      "color": 15258703,
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "Staff Name",
          "value": staff,
          "inline": true
        },
        {
          "name": "Compensated's Name",
          "value": user,
          "inline": true
        },
          {
          "name": "Rubio Link",
          "value": rubio
        }
        ],
             "footer": {
        "text": "Compensation Recorder v1"
      }
  }] 
 }),
 
};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, options);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
function test(){
  var staff = "johnny";
  var user = "timmy";
  var rubio = "www.ogm.com";
  var amount = "155555";

postAddRecordMessageToDiscord(user,staff,rubio,amount);
}
```

So far that works perfectly fine for sending the message however there seems to be very little on how to make embeds work with google scripts.

i know it can be done as i've seen a someone who's sending his info from his google sheets to his documents and he created a userform as well however each attempt i've tried seems to break everything.

I've tried adding embeds like discords API says to but it doesn't seem to work and now i'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, please add `contentType: "application/json"` to `options` as follows, and test it again.

#### From:

```
var options = {
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
```

#### To:

```
var options = {
  contentType: "application/json",  // <--- Added
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
```

#### Note:

- When I tested the modified script using your request body, I could confirm that the modified script worked. From this, I think that your object of `payload` for "embed" is correct.

#### References:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [Embed Object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object)

Comment: that is wierd, i had to remove that to make it work with just a message. Guess things change when embeds are added? haha cheers